# Can you pleaseexplain this smart contract? I understand what it does, but i do't understand the math behind it. How does paidPayouts gets incremented?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Deed {
    address payable public beneficiary;
    address public lawyer;
    uint public earliest;
    uint public amount;
    uint constant public  PAYOUTS = 10;
    uint constant public  INTERVAL = 10;
    uint public paidPayouts;

    constructor(address payable _beneficiary, address _lawyer, uint offset) payable {
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        lawyer = _lawyer;
        earliest = block.timestamp + offset;
        amount = msg.value / PAYOUTS;
    }

    function withdraw() external {
        require(msg.sender == lawyer, "only laywer can withdraw");
        require(block.timestamp >= earliest, "you can only withdraw after a specific period specified by the contract");
        require(paidPayouts < PAYOUTS, "no payouts left");
        uint elligiblePayouts = (block.timestamp - earliest) / INTERVAL;
        uint duePayouts = elligiblePayouts - paidPayouts;
        paidPayouts += duePayouts;
        beneficiary.transfer(duePayouts * amount);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The contract is quite simpl e. It divides the initial deposited `amount` into `PAYOUTS` parts. Every `INTERVAL` seconds after an initial `offset` the `layer` will be able to claim a payout.

Comment: Thanks! But how does "paidPayouts" get incremented? Because, as far as l see, when you subtract it in "duePayouts", it is 0, it is not incrementing in any way

Comment: When calling withdraw in this line `paidPayouts += duePayouts`, the variable `paidPayouts` is incremented by `duePayouts`.